# VS2015 Coded UI Cross Browser with Chrome error "Value cannot be null"

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests

When running a Coded UI test against Chrome, the cross browser console appears and the chrome browser pops up (but does not display web page), but then I get an exception:

> **System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: windowHandle**  Test method
>   SFS.Test.CodedUI.Learner.TestCases.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1
>   threw exception:  System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: windowHandle
>       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl..ctor(IntPtr
>   windowHandle)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.CrossBrowserService.InitializeTopLevelWindow()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.CrossBrowserService.InitializeCrossBrowserService(String[]
>   args)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.CrossBrowserService.<>c.<.cctor>b__3_0(String[]
>   args)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.CrossBrowserService.Launch(Uri
>   uri)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.CrossBrowser.CrossBrowserFactory.Launch(Uri
>   uri)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.BrowserWindow.LaunchPrivate(Uri
>   uri)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.BrowserWindow.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestMethodInvoker.InvokeMethod[T](Func`1
>   function, UITestControl control, Boolean firePlaybackErrorEvent,
>   Boolean logAsAction)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.BrowserWindow.Launch(Uri
>   uri)    at
>   SFS.Test.CodedUI.Learner.TestCases.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1()
>   in C:\Source\SFS
>   2.0\AMS\16.2\SFS.Test.CodedUI\SFS.Test.CodedUI.Learner\TestCases\CodedUITest1.cs:line
>   28

Line 28 is the BrowserWindow.Launch statement in the code below.

I followed these instructions for installing the Selenium components for Coded UI Cross Browser Testing.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/11cfc881-f8c9-4f96-b303-a2780156628d

The coded UI test is simple:

```
[CodedUITest]
public class CodedUITest1
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void CodedUITestMethod1()
    {
        BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "chrome";

        var bw = BrowserWindow.Launch(new System.Uri("http://www.google.com"));

        var browser = new BrowserWindow();
        browser.CopyFrom(bw);

    }

}
```

I read lots of people having success with these tools, so I am thinking it might be an issue with versions.  My versions are as follows:

- VS2015 Update 1  14.0.24720.000
- chromedriver version June 4, 2016
- Selenium Browser Components version 2.43.1.0
- Google Chrome 52.0.2743.116

Do any of you have it working with VS2015? Can you tell me what versions of chromedriver, chrome and selenium browser components you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Changing chrome driver to a lower version should help. But it doesn't properly work anyway.
There is a project on github that is aimed to create an adapter between coded ui and selenium. But work is still in progress. Contributions are highly welcomed and appreciated.
https://github.com/YuriGuzun/CodedSelenium